Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Request a solution to fix Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded of WordPress.

Would this be better asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ? It isn't clear how the question relates to Ubuntu.
